# Dirac Gamma Matrices identities..

Tags: matrices, quantum-field-theory

I need your help in order to prove this relation:

$$\gamma^{\mu} \not p \gamma_{\mu}$$  that has to give me $$-2 \not p$$

I tried this:
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
\gamma^{\mu} \not p \gamma_{\mu} & = \gamma^{\mu}\big(\gamma^{\nu}p_{\nu}\big)\gamma_{\mu} \\
& = \gamma^{\mu}\big(\gamma^{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}\big)p_{\nu} \\
& = \gamma^{\mu}\big(\gamma^{\nu}\gamma_{\mu} + \gamma^{\nu}\gamma_{\mu} - \gamma^{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}\big)p_{\nu} \\
& = \gamma^{\mu}\big(2\eta^{\nu}_{\mu} - \gamma^{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}\big)p_{\nu} \\
& = 2\gamma^{\mu}\eta^{\nu}_{\mu} - \gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}p_{\nu} \\
& = 2\gamma^{\nu}p_{\nu} - 4\gamma^{\nu}p_{\nu} \\
& = -2\not p
\end{array}
$$

My question is: is this valid? And in the second line: is the passage valid? Can I exchange the order of $\gamma$ and $p$?

Thank you everybody!!

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine to me. If in doubt, [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Miscellaneous_identities) has the proof of all the common identities.

Also, the step from the first line to the second is valid because $p_\nu$ is a scalar quantity, so it commutes with the matrix product.